# Help Viewer in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2010

When I installed Visual Studio 2010, i figured out that it was not having a traditional windows based Help Viewer. The help topics were loaded in the Internet explorer.

1.I understand that online and offline help will be consistant if we use IE. Other than this, is there any reason for having the local help in the IE?

2.Is it possible to have a traditional Help Viewer? If possible How?

Comment: Related question I asked that has an answer to address your #2 point: http://superuser.com/questions/142282/how-to-pin-visual-studio-2010-documentation-shortcut-to-windows-7-taskbar