# Windows 7: Cannot pin application to the taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, pinning

> **Note:** Since the superuser is also a wiki, here is the
>   solution to a problem i had. Others will have the same problem too.

"*I cannot pin an application to the taskbar in Windows 7.*"

Comment: This is really a bizarre design decision!  Thanks for the info.  Does editing the registry key work without breaking anything?

Comment: Can you please edit the question so that it remains a question and post answer ? Also, CW was not really needed :)

Comment: @Shinrai i don't know, i assume so. But having your install program mess with the Windows settings, which is also the user's preferences, is a bad thing. i know *why* it was done; the pinned list and the recently used list of the start menu are very much linked (for now). And they didn't want help files and uninstallers to get onto the MRU list.

Comment: @Sathya Reformed as question with answer. What's "CW"?

Comment: @Ian Thanks. CW == Community Wiki. generally Community wiki is used to mark for those questions which have no definite answer - but since this question has a definite answer, marking it as Community Wiki was not really needed. But anyways, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Sathya Ahhh. Well, i figured since i was answering it myself: somebody would get grumpy. ("Closed as not a real question", and whatnot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pin an application or shortcut to the taskbar if it contains any of the reserved words:

- Documentation
- Help
- Install
- More Info
- Readme
- Read me
- Read First
- Setup
- Support
- What's New
- Remove

This list is stored in the registry:

```
KEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   \SOFTWARE
    \Microsoft
     \Windows
      \CurrentVersion
       \Explorer
        \FileAssociation

AddRemoveNames  REG_SZ  Documentation;Help;Install;More Info;Readme;Read me;Read First;Setup;Support;What's New;Remove
```

In my case i could not pin our bug tracking application `HelpDesk` to the taskbar.
So i renamed my shortcut to `HalpDesk`.

[image]

### See also

- [Application that won’t Pin to Taskbar in Windows 7](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/32765.aspx)
- [KB282066](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282066) - [Frequently Used Programs Not Automatically Added to the Start Menu](http://www.digitalsupporttech.com/mskb/282/282066_Frequently_used_programs_not_automatically_added_to_the_Start_menu.htm)
- [.NET 3.5 Pin to Taskbar Missing](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/a63657da-84a9-41e8-aa09-6b49f3a73dcd)